# How to place a button in the center of Relative layout?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-relativelayout, center-align

I'm trying to put a button on the center app ...
Can someone explain to me what exactly this code is doing ?

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams BD = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    BD.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    BD.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

Comment: just use android:layout_centerInParent = "true" or RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT

Answer (score 2):

What this code does is

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams BD = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
```

Above line tells the view to occupy only the space it required.

```
BD.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
BD.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

The above two lines tell the LayoutManager to keep this view in Center both in horizontal and Vertical.

You should read about [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) and [RelativeLayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
Button btnNewButton;
relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
    btnNewButton = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    btnNewButton.setText("Button Text");

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams BD = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    BD.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    BD.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    btnNewButton.setLayoutParams(BD);

    relativeLayout.addView(btnNewButton);
    setContentView(relativeLayout);
```

I hope it will help you